# using multiple LIKE in mysql on multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I was wondering if someone could help with the syntax of this mysql Query:
I am joining multiple tables with a search term (LIKE %%). It works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 
WHERE table1.town=table2.town
AND table1.car=table2.car

AND `name` LIKE "%search-term%"
```

until I add another 'LIKE':

```
OR `car` LIKE "%search-term%"
```

which then appends anything like 'car' to ALL results  in table1. the AND OR works for me when using one table but confuses it when on two or more JOINED tables.. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 
WHERE table1.town=table2.town
AND table1.car=table2.car

AND ( table1.name LIKE "%search-term%"
OR table2.car LIKE "%search-term%" )
order by table1.name
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it is an AND and an AND rather than an OR. I get the same result as before if I use OR instead though

Comment: BRILLIANT! thanks, that works. Good ol' brackets. Thanks again